# PHP - MySQL ShortCut {}

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is there any way to create something like this ?

For example ,

```
if i type => {header} , php load website's navbar<br/>
if i type => {footer} , php load footer <br/>
if i type => {title} , php load data from database and set in site title , and etc...<br/>
```

thanks and sorry for my bad english

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">{header}</div>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
       </tr>
       {data_table}
    </table>
    <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its ok, there is no problem if your english is bad, but please share your tried code. It looks bit broad.

Comment: i need to know how i can do this ? @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2815635/niklesh

Answer (score 0):

You should create this using template view. I have seen something like this in opencart.

They do like in this manner, give below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"><?php echo $header; ?></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $data_table; ?>
</table>
<div class="footer"><?php echo $footer; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And they create controller and view for them all separately..